# squashed then re-squashed give different size?

Tags: linux, hex, embedded-linux, bin, firmware

I extracted a

> firmware.bin

using fmk mod kit and gave me 3 files: `header.img , rootfs.img and footer.img`
now whenever I cat and repack all the files together in `firmware2.bin` again, it works and it upgrades the router.
but when I unsquash the rootfs.img using this command  `unsquashfs rootfs.img` into `squashfs-root/`
then I squash it again using  `mksquashfs rootfs-root/ squash_new.img -comp lzma -b 131072` "which it by the way the same compression method and block size as the original `rootfs.img`"
but it gives me a less size comparing to the `rootfs.img` and the router gives me upgrade failed

here are the sizes of the 2 files

> squash_new.img (9,945,088 bytes)
>
> rootfs.img (9,945,232 bytes)

is there a problem with unsquashfs or mksquashfs?

because when I used a hex editor software, I noticed some entries are different although I have not changed anything.

Comment: What the `file rootfs.img` shows originally and after `mksquashfs`?

Comment: squash_new.img (9,945,088 bytes)

rootfs.img (9,945,232 bytes)

this... but someone said that I might have to edit the header, I have very few information about what to edit in the header file.
can someone teach me?